# JFrame in java jframe.add(button);

Tags: java, swing

I have to write:  jframe.getContentPane().add(button);

But I found out that it also works when I only write

jframe.add(button);

What are the differences between the two approaches? Is it favorable to write JFrame.getContentPane().add(button); ?

Comment: Please spare a moment to peek through the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane) :-)

Answer (score 3):

It a matter of taste. I always use getContentPane().add(..), as I think it is easier to read / know what's actually going on

Comment: +1, true to my eyes, since both means the same thing, since whatever you write, both the statements will add the said `JComponent` to the `CENTER` of the `Content Pane` of the `JFrame` :-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I got mixed up with what was "latter" I corrected my post. Tx!

Comment: @NidhiShah JFrame.add just calls getContentPane().add

Answer (score 2):

Try this........

**Before the arrival of Java 1.5**, jframe.getContentPane().add(button) was Used..... and thats was the legal way of doing it....

**But then from Java 1.5 and onwards, included the myframe.add(button)... as also one of the legal way of doing it..**  Its just like, **accessing the static variable with the Classname is the legal way of doing it...but still you can access the static variables using the class instance...**

Comment: Here is a link from the [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane), which describes the whole thing in more detail :-)

Comment: Thanks nIcE cOw, but i just hope you agree with my answer, or do i need to edit it some way.. ???

Comment: Purely, I agree with your answer, though the Strings are still attached with the usage of the two terms, that's why the related link, as very much explained by @HovercraftFullOfEels , in one of the comments, though removed later :-) Though even myself not sure, since with which version came what, since never used Java 1.5 :(

Answer (score 1):

So you should know that elements like `JButton`, `JTextArea` etc. should be added to `Container` and your method:

```
getContentPane()
```

returns the `Container` object for this frame. So both approaches work same but second approach you should use.

In the case if you will have big *application* with many elements first approach is less *readable* and second is generally recommended.

Difference isn't:

> Jframe.add() - Appends the specified component to the end of this container. This is
>   a convenience method for Container.addImpl.

Comment: but what is differance between jframe.add(button); and JFrame.getContentPane().add(button);

Answer (score 1):

The [class javadoc of `JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) is rather clear on this

> The JFrame class is slightly incompatible with Frame. Like all other JFC/Swing top-level containers, a JFrame contains a JRootPane as its only child. The content pane provided by the root pane should, as a rule, contain all the non-menu components displayed by the JFrame. This is different from the AWT Frame case. As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary. This means you can write:

```
   frame.add(child);
```

> And the child will be added to the contentPane.